# What is an adjective made from a verb called? For instance, "disconnected" in "a disconnected phone"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, past-participles

What would you call an adjective that is created from a verb?

Typically, the adjective comes from the past participle form of the verb. For example:

> A *disconnected* phone
>
> A *possessed* man
>
> An *inspired* art piece

You wouldn't say these words are past participles, because they are not, they are adjectives. What type of adjective are they, though?

Comment: You already called them 'verbs,' in fact, 'past participle form of the verb,' then why would you think they're not 'participles'?

Answer (score 1):

The OED has entries for them all as adjectives. When any adjective occurs before a noun in this way, it’s an attributive adjective.

Comment: When I was looking this up, I ran across the terms *participial adjective* and *attributive participle*. Precisely what I was looking for, thanks for making me look somewhere I hadn't even thought of looking!

Comment: Glad you found what you wanted.